# Way to disable background gesture/tap actions behind floating action button?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I am developing an app in flutter using the google_maps_flutter package. I listen for user taps on the screen and record the lat/lng of that press. However, I do not want this to record the user tap when they hit the floating action button. Is there a way to disable the map behind the button?

[image: Map Screen]

Comment: Try using Stack widget!

Comment: let's make it clear first


1.  You want to save user location whenever the user taps on the screen in google Maps?
2. You don't want to save location when user tap on floating action button ? right?

Comment: 1. I am using stack widget. In the foreground is the floating action button. In the background is the google map. 
2. Yes I want the user to be able to tap anywhere on the map and add that tapped location. 

The issue is that when the user clicks the floating action button to confirm their selected coordinates, it also adds the location where that floating action button was. 

So essentially, when the user clicks the floating action button that is overlaid with the map, I don’t want to register as a “tapped latitude/longitude”

Comment: Also add your code for getting what you have done so far